# pyttsx3 not working on freshly installed windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I have freshly installed windows 10 and I am trying to run the following code.

```
import pyttsx3;
engine = pyttsx3.init();
engine.say("I will speak this text");
engine.runAndWait() ;
```

This use to work on my previous windows 10 installation but now it is giving me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 44, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ayush/Desktop/sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init();
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am using python 3.6.6 64 bit on windows 10.

I have spent many hours trying different solutions like reinstalling python, tried python versions 3.5 and 3.7, reinstalling pyttsx3, also tried solutions given in few related questions but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This suggest that you have a 32 bit dependency somewhere and you should either find a 64 bit version, or use a 32 bit python to run instead of a 64 bit. Alternatively, it could mean that a required DLL can't be found on the path.

Comment: how do I find out if I have 32 bit dependency as I am using 64 bit windows with 64 bit python and also if some DLL is missing is there any way to find out which one is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `win32api.pyd` (which really is DLL) **is not a win32 application**. So I think it's loading 64bit drivers to 32bit runtime.

In this case, I will try to uninstall 64bit python, delete it's folder and install a 32bit version. I believe this will solve your problem, since you don't really need 64bit python.

---

Now the problem is in `win32*.pyd`s, so it seems like your **`pyttsx3` is 32bit**.

> **According to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/)**, you can try `pip install pypiwin32` to fix both *win32* and *win32api* errors.

Comment: Are you quoting from elsewhere (if so, please provide a link), or are you misusing the quote block for emphasis?

Comment: misusing the block quote to separate my opinion (what would I do in this case); edited answer

Comment: I'd suggest just introducing it as your opinion (which you already do in the way it is phrased), and not adding unnecessary styling :)

Comment: Thanks. there was problem with pywin32 module. I  downloaded source code and build it for 64 bit version of python.

Answer (score -1):

I tried installing Python 32 bits but customized with all options available such as a complete library, doing this worked wonders in breaking the errors! Just lauch the .exe launcher again, hit Modify and then just install every option!